# SSRS Format a multi-value field

Tags: sql, reporting-services, bids, ssrs-grouping

I have a number field in my ssrs report that has multiple values separated by a comma. I want to convert the number to currency but I get an error when the field has more than on value. I'm converting the text box to currency and added the (*) operator to multiply by .01 so my numbers are not inflated. I'm sure the comma is what causing the error as BIDS is expecting a number, but I'm not sure how to write the expression so that it only modifies the numbers in the string.

=Fields!field_A.Value * .01

```
Field
Number1 = converts to currency($Number1)
Number1, Number2 = #Error
number1, number2, number3 = #error
```

Comment: Check out this post - if you need to extract just the Number1 section from the field, you can use the answer's code (modified to extract based on a comma, not a blank space). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819335/remove-all-characters-after-first-white-space-in-ssrs-2005

Comment: What is the complete expression for the text box field?

Comment: I don't want to extract, I want the additiona number values to also have the currency value.
 so if Number1, Number2 = $number1, $number2 and the same if there is a third value

Comment: Do you need decimals as well, or just the $ sign?

Comment: need decimals. i'm getting the number from ssms so if the value is 1000, i need it to be $10.00. that why I'm multiplying by .01

Comment: Is there a known limit to the number of numbers in a single field?

Comment: Where are you getting this data from??

Comment: the limit is undetermined. it can be one number to a set of 10 possibly more.

Comment: If there was a limit, I'd say to use this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928888/ssrs-expression-to-split-string-possible) ... but with no limit, I'd tell you to go back to your data source and use some sort of function to split, format, and rearrange your data.

Comment: I created a proc and I'm already splitting the string. I want the report to look the way it does, I just need to make sure each number value has a decimal place and the currency symbol

Comment: @AHiggins I don't want to split the values into a row each, I need the values to stay in one row. the solution you suggested would over complicate what I need

Comment: Can you change your proc to do the formatting / multiplication as part of the csv concatenation?

Comment: I can but the formatting should be done on the front end. that would hinder performance and I'm already pulling a large amount of data. hopefully someone has an answer for me

Comment: and formatting in the proc would still leave the problem where I need every value to have a currency symbol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use embedded code in the report to do the processing of the string. This allows you to use the full VB.NET language. From the report menu in SSRS select `Report Properties` and select the `Code` section on the left. (This is in VS2010, I'm not sure what version of SSRS you're building in.)

Then you can use a VB.NET function like the one below to do the actual string processing. I'm not sure exactly how you want the output so you'll want to read the MSDN page on the [FormatNumber()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfta99yt(v=vs.90).aspx) VB.NET function.

```vb
Function ConvertCashString(orig As String)
    Dim newString As String = ""
    For Each s As String In orig.Split(",")
        Dim parsedString As Double
        If (Double.TryParse(s, parsedString)) Then
            newString += "$" + FormatNumber(parsedString * 0.01, 2, TriState.True, TriState.UseDefault, TriState.False) + ", "
        End If
    Next

    Return newString
End Function
```

Then in the report itself you can call the function like so:

```
 =Code.ConvertCashString(Fields!dbString.Value)
```

You should also read the MSDN page: [Add Code to a Report (SSRS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156028.aspx)